# Object instance is stripped of its methods

Tags: javascript, object, instance

For an online board game I am making, I have defined a `Tile` class, whose instances I use to create a "map". The `Tile` class has several properties, and a method called `show` which displays the instance on the canvas.

All the scripts are passed on to the clients as static files via script tags in the `index.html` which is served by node.js. The instantiation of the `Tile` class worked properly before I introduced the server. Now it produces some very weird and interesting results.

The `HexMap` class, creates upon instantiation a 2d array of `Tile`s as follows:

```
function HexMap (width, height, image) {
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.contents = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < this.width; i++) {
        this.contents[i] = [];
        for (let j = 0; j < this.height; j++)
            this.contents[i].push(new Tile(i, j, size, image, "SEA"));
    }

}
```

The code for the `Tile` class is this:

```
var Tile = function (row, column, side, image, type) {

Vector.call(this, row, column);

this.unit = null;
this.canvas = null;
this.side = side;

this.type = type;

this.startingPoint = new Vector(this.x*Math.sqrt(3)*this.side + (this.y& 1) * this.side*Math.sqrt(3)/2, this.side*1.5*this.y);
this.middlePoint = new Vector(this.startingPoint.x + Math.sqrt(3)*this.side/2, this.startingPoint.y + this.side/2);

this.getOffset = function () {
    return {
        "SEA" : 0,
        "SHORELINE" : 60,
        "PLAINS" : 120,
        "FOREST_LIGHT" : 180,
        "FOREST_HEAVY" : 240,
        "MOUNTAINS" : 300,
        "SWAMP" : 360,
        "MARSH" : 420
    }[this.type];
};

this.getVector = function () {
    return new Vector(this.x, this.y);
};

this.show = function (context) {
    if(!this.canvas){
        this.canvas = makeTemplate(side, this.type, image);
    }
    context.drawImage(this.canvas, this.startingPoint.x - this.getOffset(), this.startingPoint.y);
};

this.getPixelX = function () {
    return this.x*Math.sqrt(3)*this.side + (this.y & 1) * this.side;
};

this.getPixelY = function () {
    return this.side/2 + this.side*2*this.y;
};

this.setType = function (type){
    this.type = type;
};

};
```

Printing a `Tile` object in the console would normally display something like this:

```
Tile {x: 0, y: 0, unit: null, canvas: canvas, side: 15, …}
```

I tried the same thing using the server this time, and the result is this:

```
{x: 0, y: 1, unit: null, canvas: null, side: 15, …}
```

Interestingly enough, the result is indeed an object, but not a `Tile` object. It has all the properties a `Tile` object has, but has none of its methods.
The error I end up getting is this:

```
tile.show is not a function
```

The map object is created and transferred to the server via `socket.io` sockets. The following piece of code runs on the client (the guest).

```
function selectGame(id) {
        var hexmap = new HexMap(rowspan, colspan, spritesheet);
        hexmap.generateIsland();
        socket.emit('game-select', {id: id, hexmap: hexmap});
    }
```

The server then receives the map:

```
socket.on('game-select', function (data) {

    //The 2 sockets corresponding to the players join the same room
    io.sockets.connected[data.id].join(games[data.id].identifier);
    io.sockets.connected[socket.id].join(games[socket.id].identifier);

    //The start-game event is emitted for just the sockets of the same room
    io.to(games[socket.id].identifier).emit('start-game', {
        map: data.hexmap
    });

});
```

Then both the clients receive it again:

```
    socket.on('start-game', function (data) {
        let el = document.getElementById("wrapper");
        el.parentNode.removeChild(el);
        hexmap = data.map;
        contexts = setupCanvas();
        displayMap(hexmap, contexts.mapContext);
    });
```

What `displayMap` does is it iterates through the contents of the map, and displays each `Tile` using its `show` method.

I cannot pin down the problem no matter how hard i try... Any suggestion on how to solve this?

Comment: Are you performing some sort of copying of tiles?

Comment: Does the issue go away if you remove the node.js components? What does `Vector.call` do?

Comment: @PlanB, `new` is not specific to ES6. Has been there quite a long while ;-)

Comment: @nem035 One of the 2 players creates the room (host) and the other one (guest) joins it. Since the map is generated randomly but the 2 players playing the game have to have the same map, the guest creates a map, sends it to the server, and the server sends it to the host. In a way this procedure could be considered "copying" the tiles. Other than that, no other copying is done

Comment: I suggest this: change `var Tile = function ` to `function Tile`: there is a difference in what the name of the function is, and the name of the variable. Although they should be equivalent since ES5 ("inferred function name").

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ there is a `Vector` class i have defined in another script, and by `Vector.call` i create a new vector and set it as a property of the `Tile` object.

Comment: Can you show the code where you send a map to the server? Is there some kind of JSON serialization happening? You can't transmit real JS objects to and from the server. If it is being serialized, that's what your methods are dropping off.

Comment: @trincot I changed the definitions as per your suggestion. Thanks for letting me know about the best practices. Unfortunately the problem seems to be elsewhere...

Comment: the result of `new Tile` is going to be a `Tile`, unless you include an explicit `return` statement in your constructor that returns something else. This smells ***very*** strongly of object serialization/deserialization, which happens when you pass an object over the network, e.g., with socket.io. Are you certain that the object you are logging actually came from a `new Tile` call (important: on that same machine!), or did it *really* come from a network-listening callback function that was supplied the value (e.g., `socket.on(tiles=>...)`)?

Comment: @apsillers I do use socket.io to transfer the objects to and from the server. Can you please explain what serialization/deserialization means?

Comment: socket.io uses `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` to turn object into JSON string to send over the network. This strips out function properties (since functions cannot be represented in JSON) and prototypes (since JSON has no concept of inheritance), leaving only the non-function properties that actually exist directly on the object being serialized. Since you're using socket.io, I'm sure there is a duplicate of this somewhere; I'll look now.

Comment: Some duplicates: [Socket.io passing javascript object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30550076/710446) and [emited objects from server lose their functions and name once received by client](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44532466/710446)

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ the code was added, sorry it took as long as it took...

Comment: @Alan: in the end, you need to construct the Tiles and Maps on the client side. If you want to share data between clients and servers, you will have to share only enough information so that you can reconstruct your objects on the client side. JSON is a string representation of a JS object, but it doesn't support functions. Think of it this way: a JS object, in your browser, for that version, on your OS a just a chunk of bits in memory. You cannot send a real JS object over the network and expect to work in everyone else's browser on their OS. That's where serialization/deserialization comes in

Comment: @apsillers What you described fits the problem perfectly, i will look into the links you provided. Thank you.

Comment: The (too) short answer is: given a network-transferred tile `t`, the client needs to do a `new Tile(t.x, t.y, t.size, ...)` etc. on receipt of the deserialized tile-like structure. You could write this directly into your `Tile` constructor, too, so you can just do `new Tile(t)` and have the constructor pull out the right properties from the network-transferred object.

Comment: @Cᴏʀʏ If that's true then I may as well start mourning the weeks of work that were invested into this... I was hoping it could be avoided, but i had no prior experience with servers...

Comment: @apsillers That's a very interesting solution. Ideally we could create the map from  a seed, and transfer the seed around, but thinking back 2 months ago, I had no idea such a problem would come up

Comment: I wouldn't fret too much, this is afterall going to be a great learning experience once you have it all working. This is one reason I still love [so]. You're really not too far off. You can send basically the parameters you are passing to the constructor of HexMap and Tile back and forth across the network. You just need to keep a live HexMap instance on each client, and use sockets to update their properties and redraw your canvas. @apsillers has great suggestions in this comment thread as well.